# Electrical outlet clearance from a hot water panel radiator

Tags: electrical, receptacle, nec, radiant-heating, clearance

What is the clearance of an electrical outlet from a hot water panel radiator? So facing the wall with a window and having a panel radiator down below hanged/fixed on the wall, how far away left and right can you place an outlet? BY THE CODE.

By the code, any wall has to have an outlet. The spacing between receptacles, according to the NEC, it is 12 feet with no point along a wall being more than 6 feet from a receptacle.

So, how do I handle this? The bedroom is 10 by 13.5 feet and the wall in case is 10 feet with 5.3 feet window opening. The radiator below is 47 inches wide.

[image]

[image]

Credits for the second image for [houseneeds](https://www.houseneeds.com/learning-center/hydronic-radiator-installation/myson-hydronic-radiator-install-1)

Comment: I take it this is a *hydronic* radiant panel?

Comment: Yes it is. It is Type 21 which means has only one layer of vertical fins.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the NEC, but the CEC refers to *usable* wall space when calculating distances between receptacles; do not count the space behind an open bedroom door or under a window sill; these areas are not considered 'usable' wall space. I have found receptacles to be most usable when located closest to corners of rooms, where possible. The CEC says receptacles shall not be located above radiators; it says nothing about locating receptacles beside rads. I supose you could install them as close as practicle to the sides of the rads, but why bother? Adding an extra plug may solve your headache; they're inexpensive. I would put one in each of the three corners and one on each wall.